# Why will my program not display more than one line of data

Tags: java

I try putting in more than one line of contacts but it only displays the first contact. I enter in a name followed by a number. I say yes to having another contact, and then enter in the second name and number. Now I say no more contacts and it only prints the first contact. I need to be able to print all of my contacts.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PhoneBook {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String contact;
        int moreContact=1;
        int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to add a new contact?");
        int i = 0;
        java.io.File c = new java.io.File("contacts.txt");
        java.io.PrintWriter b = new java.io.PrintWriter(c);

        if (choice == 0) {
            do {
                String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Contact Name: ");
                String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Contact Number: ");

                contact=(name + " "+ number);
                b.println(contact);
                b.close();
                moreContact = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you have another contact?");
            } while (moreContact==0);
        }

        java.io.File h = new java.io.File("contacts.txt");
        java.util.Scanner list = new java.util.Scanner(h);
        while (list.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(list.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You `.close()` your writer after writing a line to it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You close the file after accepting one contact in the `do .. while()` loop:

```
b.close();
```

No surprises that you see one contact.  Close it outside of the loop instead.

Comment: If I don't close it, it will not show me any contacts. Where is an appropriate place to close it? there is no method I know of to reopen it.

Comment: You close it, but after the do  while loop. It dhould show the contacts